# How to maintain records order with the exact order of table in linq query?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable

I am having `2 datatables with following records in dataset`:

**SubvariantCodes:**

```
Code              Desc
Sub1              Subvariant1
Sub2              Subvariant2
Sub3              Subvariant3
Sub4              Subvariant4
```

**dtVariant:**

```
Name        Type        status
Variant1    Division    active
Variant2    Division    active
Variant3    Division    active
```

**dtSubVariant:**

```
Name        Type             Code 
Variant1    Division         Sub1
Variant1    Division         Sub3
Variant2    Division         Sub1
Variant2    Division         Sub2
Variant2    Division         Sub3
Variant2    Division         Sub4
Variant3    Division         Sub1
Variant3    Division         Sub2
```

Now i want to get `Subvariant codes unique list type wise for only those variant whose status is active with the same ordering of those Subvariant codes as they are in SubvariantCodes datatable.`

**Expected output:**

```
Division: Sub1,Sub2,Sub3,Sub4
```

**Code**:

```
var data = (from master in Ds1.Tables["dtVariant"].Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                     join child in Ds1.Tables["dtSubVariant"].Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                     on new 
                     { 
                         X1 = master.Field<string>("Name"),
                         X2 = master.Field<string>("Type"), 
                         X3 = master.Field<string>("Code")
                     }
                     equals new 
                     {
                         X1 = child.Field<string>("Name"),
                         X2 = child.Field<string>("Type"),
                         X3 = child.Field<string>("Code")
                     }
                     where master.Field<string>("status") == "active"
                     group child by child.Field<string>("Type") into cms
                     select new
                     {
                         names = (from dp in cms
                                  join subvariantcode in Ds1.Tables["SubvariantCodes"].AsEnumerable()
                                  on dp.Field<string>("Code") equals subvariantcode.Field<string>("Code")
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      Names = subvariantcode.Field<string>("Code".ToLower()),
                                  }).Distinct().ToList()
                     }).ToList();
```

But here with above query i am getting below output in which i am getting **Sub3 at 2nd position but in my SubvariantCodes table sub3 is at 3rd position**

```
Division: Sub1,Sub3,Sub2, Sub4
```

Is this possible to do in linq query???

Comment: You should use `DataTable.AsEnumerable()` and not `DataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()`, it's simpler and essentially does the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve your goal, it will be sufficient to exchange the outer and inner sequences in this join:

```
names = (from dp in cms
         join subvariantcode in Ds1.Tables["SubvariantCodes"].AsEnumerable()
         on dp.Field<string>("Code") equals subvariantcode.Field<string>("Code")
```

like this:

```
names = (from subvariantcode in Ds1.Tables["SubvariantCodes"].AsEnumerable()
         join dp in cms
         on subvariantcode.Field<string>("Code") equals dp.Field<string>("Code")
```

This behavior is mentioned in the [`Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675(v=vs.110).aspx) method documentation - **Remarks** section:

> Join<TOuter, TInner, TKey, TResult> **preserves the order of the elements of outer**, and for each of these elements, the order of the matching elements of inner.